# Why is Perl market position in server-side scripting so low, even less than Java?

Tags: perl

As per the article at [W3Techs](http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/pl-php/all/all), Perl ranks the lowest among the server side scripting languages, even less than Java? Is there any reason behind it? Perl, as far as I see, is very popular, and an awesome language, how come it is hardly used by websites? Does it have issues with server side scripting?

Comment: This is possibly one of the open-ended questions which Stackoverflow isn't designed for - http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: Reminds me of [madeupstats](https://twitter.com/madeupstats)...

Comment: Voting to close as non-constructive → soliciting debate, arguments

Comment: This proves only that if you base statistics on flawed data gathering techniques, you get flawed statistics.  Also proves that many people can be easily deceived by flawed statistics.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This article has a lot of details on how W3Techs gets their data: http://w3techs.com/blog/entry/usage_of_perl_for_websites_fell_below_1_percent

As i did some analysis on this, let me summarize in short that the data presented by W3Techs is deeply flawed and extremely misleading. First off, it is important to know that they detect technologies of sites by running simple scripts at them that look for file suffixes in urls and then just take that and **never verify with the site owner**. As such they have a "no-detect" rate of 17.6% (plus an **unknown** "false-detect" rate). A more correct version of their chart would be this:

[image]

If you'd like to get more details and more mistakes in their data methodology, please take a look at the comments of the article, especially those written by "Mithaldu" or "Christian Walde", i.e. me. I posted extensively there as to why their data is nearly useless and why they're even misinterpreting the data they do have.

Comment: Ummm, I didn't get the minimum and maximum thing. Please explain. And where is the link to the article you mentioned? What is the source of your data?

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't aware that the question linked to another page on W3Techs, i edited the answer to explain what i am talking about.

Comment: The article is an amazingly bad example of uselessness. IMHO, the most important bar they don't show (as you point out as well) is the "the web sites whose technology we can't deduce" compared to all others.

Comment: Most modern Perl web frameworks don't leave a fingerprint that would be easy to detect unless configured to do so.  Mojolicious, for example, doesn't require that URL's end in ".pl", and in fact, it would make no sense for them to do so.  Mojolicious has a plugin that will set a "powered by" x-header field, but aside from explicit configuration it would be impossible to detect that Perl is powering a Mojolicious-based website.  I suspect the same is true of Catalyst and Dancer.  So the data gathering method is only showing sites that use old-style technology that exposes script names.

Comment: David: You're correct. In such instances Perl can only be detected by asking the site owner.